# Shell, find line containing, and replace on only line after it

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file located at: `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/info.plist`. I am trying to find the line that contains `LSUIElement` and then replace that whole line with `<string>firefox</string>`.

This is what I got, so far, it does nothing:

```
line=“LSUIElement”
rep="<string>firefox</string>"
sed -e "s/${line}/${rep}/g" /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/info.plist > /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/info.plist.profilist
mv /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/info.plist.profilist /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/info.plist
```

Comment: If you want to manipulate plist files, you would be better off using `plutil` in conjunction with an XML or JSON manipulation tool.  Not sure why you would want to set `LSUIElement` to the value `"firefox"`, though; it's normally either absent or set to `"0"` or `"1"` depending on whether or not you want Firefox to appear in the Dock.

Comment: Thanks @Mark I created a `.app` on my desktop which launches `Firefox.app` with command line arguments so it opens in a profile other then default. But if I right click and say "keep in dock" on that icon. then on future clicks of that icon, its opening my default profile :(

Comment: Do you want to replace that line ("and then replace that whole line with") or the next line ("and replace on only line after it")? The rest of the line? The whole line? The pattern? This are all different options.

Comment: @userunknown Typically in the plist.info we have `<key>LSUIElement</key>` on a line, then on the line after it we have `<string>1</string>`. So I am trying to replace the line after it which is `<string>1</string>` with `<string>firefox</string>`. If no new line then it should handle it too.

Comment: Well, I don't have such a file, and maybe you can reword your question, to make it more clear. In the more simple case, you have either both expression in the right order on one line or the second in the next line. But can we assume, that if it is already in the same line, there will not be a matching <string>1<string> in the next line? This could be handled easily with 2 sed commands, one for each case. Handling both at the same time would be rather a complex problem for sed (or for me), which I use for it's convenience :) and only to a certain degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **awk**, you can do something like this:

```
awk '/LSUIElement/{i=NR+1}{if(NR==i){gsub(/1/,"0",$0)}}1' File > tmp && mv tmp File
```

**Logic:**
if `LSUIElement` is found, set variable `i` to `NR+1` (i.e the next line /record number). As second part, if `NR` (current record/line) is `i` (previously saved), substitute `1` with `0`. Thus substitution will happen only in the line following the line with pattern `LSUIElement`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify the problem for those, who don't have such a plist-file at hand.

```
echo -e "foo bar baz\nthe suspicious LSUIElement in line 2\nand some more garbage" > luis.txt 
cat luis.txt
foo bar baz
the suspicious LSUIElement in line 2
and some more garbage

line=“LSUIElement”
rep="<string>firefox</string>"
```

So here we have problem 1: Slashes in sed expression normally separate the parts like in 's/a/b/g'.

```
sed -e "s/${line}/${rep}/g" luis.txt > luis2.txt 
mv luis2.txt luis.txt
```

We first go for the low hanging fruit. Sed, at least Gnu-sed, has an option -i to alter the file in place. In the background, there might be a 
copy being made, since often the file will shrink or grow, so it is hard to avoid, but we don't need the redirection and mv:

```
sed -i "s/${line}/${rep}/g" luis.txt
```

You might even let sed produce a backup file. AFAIK sed doesn't need -e in normal cases, but it might be, that gnu-sed is special in that case. Test or read the man page.

Now for the hard part. We test without -i to avoid destruction. First test, first surprise:

```
line=“LSUIElement”
rep="<string>firefox</string>"
echo $line
# “LSUIElement”
echo $rep
# <string>firefox</string>
```

Why does *line* show quotes, but *rep* doesn't? Ah, these are typographical quotes? Is this of any importance? Then you should mention it, because it's easy to oversee. I decide to go without them until demand.

If we replace the / in the sed-expression with |, we can avoid collision with sed-syntax in the $rep variable:

```
sed "s|${line}|${rep}|g" luis.txt
foo bar baz
the suspicious <string>firefox</string> in line 2
and some more garbage
```

Here we replaced exactly the pattern, not the line.

```
sed "s|.*${line}.*|${rep}|g" luis.txt
foo bar baz
<string>firefox</string>
and some more garbage
```

This was replacing the whole line.

```
sed "s|${line}.*|${rep}|g" luis.txt
foo bar baz
the suspicious <string>firefox</string>
and some more garbage
```

This was replacing from pattern inclusive till the EOL.

If we want to replace something in the next line - well replace what? For example, the *garbage*?

We can match on $line without replacing it, but calling a short series of 2 commands, 'n' for 'read next line' and perform our s-substitution there. Those commands have to be wrapped into {}. Since we don't need changing / to | in the former part, we switch back there:

```
sed "/${line}.*/{n;s|garbage|$rep|}" luis.txt
foo bar baz
the suspicious LSUIElement in line 2
and some more <string>firefox</string>
```

The command:

```
sed -i.bak "/${line}.*/{n;s|garbage|$rep|}" luis.txt
```

would create such a backupfile luis.txt.bak

With a pattern, as now noticed in the comment, this would look like:

```
sed -i.bak "/${line}.*/{n;s|<string>.*</string>|$rep|}" luis.txt
```

Decide, how specific (1, digits, doesn't matter) it has to be.